# in java how to INSERT records into database from multiple run() methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

In my project, I am using multiple run() methods .

In each run() method , I am getting one value So i want to insert that value into oracle DB.

I wrote DB insertion code in each run() .But it is storing only first run() method value remaining run() method values are not inserted.

So please give me suggestions to store values into database from multiple threads values.

Comment: Please post the relevant section of code (remove any credential information), otherwise it will be impossible for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your question is not that much clear however below is sample program to test your case:
Key points:
1. Check if you can use database connection pooling with some pool size based on your number of threads.
2. Commit your changes
3. Close your connections.
    public class MultithreadDatabaseEntry
    {

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      new Thread(new DBJob()).start();
      new Thread(new DBJob()).start();

   }

   public static class DBJob implements Runnable
   {
      public DBJob()
      {
      }

      @Override
      public void run()
      {
         Connection conn = null;
         Statement stmt = null;

         try
         {
            conn = getConnection();
            if(conn != null)
            {
               //Do your database operation
            }


         }
         catch (SQLException e)
         {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         finally{
            //finally block used to close resources
            try{
               if(stmt!=null)
                  stmt.close();
            }catch(SQLException se2){
            }// nothing we can do
            try{
               if(conn!=null)
                  conn.commit();
                  conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
               se.printStackTrace();
            }//end finally try
         }//

      }

   }

   //Here you can use different database connection pooling mechanism from Apache DBCP, Tomcat Pool etc
   public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
   {
      Connection conn = null;
      Statement stmt = null;
      try{

         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


         System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);


      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
         //Handle errors for Class.forName
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return conn;

   }
}
```